# Magento display message on page

Tags: validation, magento, email, post, input

I start to give my luck on magento for weeks now. Challenges since then. I am trying to display message above my input box but to no avail. Below are my phtml and controller.

password.phtml

```
<div id="account-profile">
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/emailopt'); ?>" method="post">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
    <div class="fieldset">
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="email"><?php echo $this->__('Email') ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" value="" class="required-entry input-text validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>        
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-dbbdr" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit Options') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Edit Options') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
```

accountController.php

```
    public function emailoptAction()
    { 
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) { 
        return $this->_redirect('*/emailoptions');
    }
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();        
        $_email =$this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
        if ($email != $_email) {
          echo 'This is not your valid email';
        } else {
          echo 'proceed here'; 
        }
    $this->_redirect('*/emailoptions');

    }
```

what happens here is everytime i click on submit, it just echo the message and then redirect to that page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redirecting after echoing that might not work.

Use bellow code for message display.

```
$message = $this->__('Error: This is not your valid email');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
```

More Information [here](http://www.atwix.com/magento/advanced-global-messages-manipulation/)

**UPDATE**

```
 public function emailoptAction()
        { 
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) { 
            return $this->_redirect('*/emailoptions');
        }
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $email = $customer->getEmail();        
            $_email =$this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
            if ($email != $_email) {
              //echo 'This is not your valid email';
              $message = $this->__('This is not your valid email');
              Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);

            } else {
              //echo 'proceed here'; 
              $message = $this->__('proceed here');
              Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);
            }
        $this->_redirect('*/emailoptions');

        }
```

Comment: The message with be displayed with <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?> as the messages stored in session

Comment: Just add the above code before redirect and remove echo

Comment: It is showing now. just that it is not showing in my desired location inside emailoptions.phtml which is under my.account.wrapper. It shows on very top of the page.

Comment: Message once displayed will be removed from session so u need to place <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?> code at proper place

Comment: I have it just below the submit button.

Comment: i tried adding this Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsValid(1); but still not showing in desired location.

Comment: here "Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsValid(1);"  you are forcing "is_valid" variable to be set. you need to explicitly call Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsValid()

Comment: I already added this on top of $this->_redirect(); and added <?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsValid(); ?> on phtml file. It is really weird why.

Comment: is there anything to do with my local.xml? this phtml file is link i added to my account dashboard. Basically it is under <reference name="my.account.wrapper">

Comment: Hi Dushyant.. fortunately this solved my problemm -> <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('global_messages') ?> . Thank you mate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in `admin panel` then use this

`Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Error here");`

otherwise use this for `frontend`

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Error here");`

For `checkout`

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError("Error here");`

Use these codes in your `controller`.

Easy i think

```
if ($email != $_email) {
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError("Not valid"); //change adminhtml as per need
          $this->_redirect('your page');
        } else {
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess("Valid");
          $this->_redirect('your page');
        }
```

Comment: Message already showing. I want it to display after controller validate if the email is valid or not.